# How can I reset a command cooldown for a discord user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to avoid as many errors as possible, but the bot may have errors during its runtime. You can run a command only once every 7 days. If it comes to errors that would be doofy of course. Is there a way to make a command usable once again/reset the cooldown for certain users?

**My approach:**

```py
    @trivia_channel.command(aliases=["reset"])
    async def reset_cooldown(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        await self.start.reset_cooldown(ctx, member)
        await ctx.send(f"Resetted cooldown for {member}.")
```

`trivia_channel.command` is a group command.

This obviously throws errors and I don't know how to accommodate the `member` argument.

Comment: Is `trivia_channel` a group command? Or is it an instance of `commands.Bot`?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that, it is a group command and "start" is the thing I want to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Command.reset_cooldown` only takes one argument, the `Context`. You can reset the cooldown for someone else if you overwrite the `Context.author` and `Context.message.author` attributes with the `member` variable.

```py
@trivia_channel.command(aliases=["reset"])
async def reset_cooldown(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    ctx.author = member
    ctx.message.author = member
    
    self.start.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    await ctx.send(f"Resetted cooldown for {member.mention}")
```

This worked for me, it's not the best solution though. If you want a much better way you can create a custom cooldown but it's not worth for only one command.

#### Reference:

- [`Command.reset_cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.reset_cooldown)